# UICollectionView -- get a callback when load is complete?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView.  Each cell contains a UITextField.  I want a callback when display is complete, so I can query a model object for which textField should be the firstResponder, then make it the firstResponder.  Can I get that callback?  Or is there another natural way to accomplish this?

Comment: Try this solution, it feels cleaner: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39425374/2664531

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you send the `layoutIfNeeded` message to your collection view, it will update its children (adding and deleting cells as necessary) before returning.  Thus you can make it update synchronously, then perform your post-reload actions.

```
[myCollectionView layoutIfNeeded];
[self chooseFirstResponderFromCells:myCollectionView.visibleCells];
```

Comment: architectpianist's answer may (or may not) be better for you, depending on your situation.

Comment: Your answers about UICollectionView are really helpful!

Comment: I needed to call the `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` then because somehow the collectionView was wrongly laid out after programmatically scrolling (`setContentOffset` or `scrollToItemAtIndexPath`)

Answer (score 5):

As far as an actual callback method, I don't think there is one for collection view loading. The only one I know is `performBatchUpdates:completion`, and that's pretty unrelated. In my experience, though, collection views are loaded and ready to go by the time `viewDidAppear` is called, so I would set the first responder there.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it but you might do it by putting code in

```
dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
```

to get the count of visible cells (maybe [visibleCells count]) then tracking how many have actually been processed, then making your callback after all have been displayed.  You'd have to reset the count between scrolls though.

Not clean, but should work.  I don't know of any way to get a callback short of that.