# reloadData in performBatchUpdates:completion: does not call cellForItemAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

So I was playing around my `UITableView` when I noticed that this code:

```
[self performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self reloadData];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

does not lead to `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` being called, only `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is called.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

I know exactly what happens in `reloadData` but this is different from that.

Comment: What thread is `reloadData` called in?

Comment: The main thread, I made sure of that.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs of `reloadData`: "It should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows, especially within an animation block implemented with calls to beginUpdates and endUpdates." Perhaps this also applies to `performBatchUpdates`.