# How to set heightForRowAt based the number of numberOfItemsInSection?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm using `UITableViewController` and put `UICollectionView` in second row in Table View Cell. The problem is how I can get heightForRowAt dynamically.

I have tried using `return UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. But not working.

Any help is really appreciated.

**viewDidLoad**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = self.tableView.rowHeight
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

**UITableViewController**

*Option 1*

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return self.tableView.bounds.width + 15
    }
```

*Option 2*

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Currently, I hard code the number of returns.

**UICollectionViewDataSource**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 15
    }
```

**UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 2.5
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 2.5

        itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width - 5.0) / 3.0
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
    }
```

Here is the image of UI using `return self.tableView.bounds.width + 15` :

[image]

Here is the image of UI using `return UITableViewAutomaticDimension` :

[image]

Here is the image of Constraints :

[image]

Comment: what are your constraint for UICollectionView?

Comment: @TusharSharma see updated questions. all set to 0.

Comment: can you show how have you used automatic dimensions? I mean what all steps have you performed?

Comment: I have update the questions.  Currently what I am doing is I set the `return self.tableView.bounds.width + 15`.  To get a long height. If I use the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` it will be normal table.

Comment: @TusharSharma, I already update the questions.

Comment: For automatic dimension to work you need to set an estimated height first. Just hardcode the estimated height, and set `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for height.

Comment: How have you set height of collectionview?

Comment: @GoodSp33d Could you please give an example. Hardcode the estimated height ?

Comment: It doesnt work like this. BCZ first your tableview is loaded and it sets its height then collection view is called and then collectionview set its height which is greater then tablecell height. So it takes first  loaded  tablecell height alays. So you need to forcefully update the tableCell Height after collectionView load.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR, No, I didnt set height

Comment: @dahiya_boy, How to forcefully update ? Could you please give suggestion ?

Comment: @Nizzam Tushar has given that example, can you try that and let us know what happens ?

Comment: If you have a label in tableviewcell its height will increase based on the label text and its cell height will increase based on label height. Here you have a collectionview in tableviewcell and it doesnt change collectionview height based on its content.  Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33364092/7250862

Comment: @RajeshkumarR, I start iOS dev with Swift. No idea on objective-C. :(

Answer (score 0):

In your viewDidLoad()  try adding this -:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       yourTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70 // this is your storyboard default cell height 
       yourtableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension //Automatic dimensions

    }
```

Then try this -:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Comment: `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = self.tableView.rowHeight`
`self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

I already implement this.

Comment: Sorry for forget to notify you the result. Its happen same as `return UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in the image.

Comment: What is your suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have to give dynamic height for your cell which has a collection view depending on the content height of your collection view, but while loading your table view that time may be your collection view would not be loaded completely thus that time your collection view's content height might not be right.

In order to get the right content height you have to calculate collection view's content height like below:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

//Your cell which has a collectionview
    if indexPath.row == 1{ 
    let contentHeight = (numberOfCollectionViewcell*itemHeight)+collectionViewContentOffset
    return contentHeight
    }
            return self.tableView.bounds.width + 15
        }
```

Comment: I dont think you can achieve this `collectionViewContentOffset` in UITableView protocol.

Comment: collectionViewContentOffset is a fixed value which is set by storyboard or by code so we can get it with the reference of collection view everywhere in the class.

Answer (score 0):

1. From CollectionViewDelegate yon can identify when collectionview is fully loaded
2. get the `CollectionView` content height.
3. Send this content height to the `tableView` VC by creating delegate.
4. In delegate method `reload tableView`.
5. In `tableViewCell`  `CollectionView` is already reloading so every time when you do above method compiler goes to infinity for reloading tableView and collectionView. For this you need to add a flag (`isForcefullyReloadCollectionView`), flag is true when tableview is tableview is need to reload otherwise false. You need to add this flag where you going to forcely reload the tableView.

Do this above, If you need further help you can ask. If I got any other solution then I update you.

Comment: what should I call to reload tableview ?
`self.tableView.reloadData` ?

Comment: @Nizzam Yeah BUT IN THE CLASS WHERE YOU HAVE TAKEN THE OUTLET OF TABLEVIEW.

Comment: Under protocol of `UICollectionViewDelegate`. At `func ....sizeForItemAt....` I try to `print(collectionView.contentSize.height)`. And it returns 0.

Comment: @Nizzam (uicollectionview-has-been-loaded-completely)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020027/how-do-i-know-that-the-uicollectionview-has-been-loaded-completely] First let the collectionview completely load, then check contentview.